# Deploy a Cloud Function to different Firebase projects

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, environment

I have two firebase projects, one for development (project-dev) and one for production (project-prod).

I initialized firebase CLI for writing and deploying cloud functions linked to project-prod. Then I ran `firebase use --add` and added project-dev so that I can deploy the same function to both projects; I don't want to rewrite the same function twice.

At this point, I faced **the problem**. Into the function, I have to write something to the realtime database, but when I deploy the function to project-dev it writes to project-prod's database.

**What I want to achieve** is that the function has to refer to the database of the project that it is deployed to. So that I have one function and when it is deployed to project-dev it writes to project-dev's database and when it is deployed to project-prod it writes to project-prod's database.

Is it possible to achieve that? If not, what's the way to go?

**EDIT**

Function code:

```
exports.AddOrders= functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    async function addOrder(key, value) {
        var ref = app.database().ref("/orders");
        return ref.child(key).set(value);
    }

    var orders = req.body['orders'];
    var promises = [];
    for (var key in orders) {
        promises.push(addOrder(key, orders[key]));
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(
        _ => {
            res.sendStatus(200);
            return null;
        }
    ).catch(err => {
        res.send(err);
    })
});
```

(This function works fine, the problem is that it writes on the wrong database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer for anyone wondering what the problem was.

He was initialising the admin sdk with the credentials of a service account tied to the production project. The solution was to change it to `admin.initializeApp()` without passing any arguments. This made Firebase use the default credentials for each project.

I know its a common mistake but again, here is the link to the corresponding documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Answer (score 10):

After you add a project with `firebase use --add <projektName>` you need to select it with `firebase use <projectName>`. Then you can deploy to the selected project with `firebase deploy` or `firebase deploy --only functions`.

Comment: Do you use any external routes to access the database or are you using the admin sdk?

Comment: I'm using the admin sdk

Comment: Can you post the code for your cloud function?

Comment: just edited the question to include the code

Comment: How and where are you triggering the cloud functions (both dev and prod)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229785/discussion-between-fabio-and-max).

Answer (score 0):

I use `firebase use` to toggle between my projects and then conditionally initialize my firebase admin code using the following code:

```
var firebase = require("firebase-admin");
const { projectID } = require("firebase-functions/params");
var path = require('path');
var { serviceAccountDev, serviceAccountProd } = require(path.resolve( __dirname, "./serviceAccountKey.js"));

if (projectID.value() === "myapp-dev") {
   firebase.initializeApp({
      credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccountDev),
      databaseURL: "https://myapp-dev-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
   });
} else {
   firebase.initializeApp({
      credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccountProd),
      databaseURL: "https://myapp-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
   });
}
```